# ADB cant run after installing Nvidia 750 GTX driver

Tags: android, adb

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Jared\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

That error starts when I installed my Nvidia geforce 750 gtx driver. Does anybody knows how to fix this? I cant run my code on any devices i connect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installlation of video driver and your error are unrelated. ADB needs administrator rights to be run, and UAC prevents it from running. The there are several paths to take: disable UAC, or go to adb.exe file properties and set 'run as administrator' flag.